# nuget tfs build 2015

Tags: nuget, tfs-2015

I am trying to use NuGet to package and publish the package with TFS Build 2015 to local NuGet Server. I am getting error , I am not sure what am i missing. Thanks for Help.

Here is Error 
Starting task: NuGet Packager

---

Set workingFolder to default: C:\Lucky\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58
Executing the powershell script: C:\Lucky\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58\NuGetPackager.ps1
Checking pattern is specified
No Pattern found in solution parameter.
Found files: 1
--File: "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s\Dev\FabrikamFiber.CallCenter"
The property DirectoryName does not exist or was not found.
Creating Nuget Arguments:
--ARGS: pack "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s\Dev\FabrikamFiber.CallCenter" -OutputDirectory "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s" -Properties Configuration=Release
Invoking nuget with pack "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s\Dev\FabrikamFiber.CallCenter" -OutputDirectory "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s" -Properties Configuration=Release on 
C:\Lucky\agent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe pack "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s\Dev\FabrikamFiber.CallCenter" -OutputDirectory "C:\Lucky\agent_work\1\s" -Properties Configuration=Release
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Please specify a nuspec or project file to use.
Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

---

Finishing task: NuGetPackager

---

Task NuGetPackager failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

Comment: What parameters are you providing to the task?

Comment: Can you share the settings of "NugetPackage" task?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Answer below is fixed it and also this link from Donovan Brown also helped me understand the flow. http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-package-and-publish-a-nuget-package-to-nuget-org-using-team-build-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error info:

> Please specify a nuspec or project file to use. Unexpected exit code 1
>   returned from tool NuGet.exe

You may specified a wrong argument in nuget package task ,please double check you have followed below requirements:

> **Specify .csproj files (for example, `**\*.csproj`) for simple projects. In this case:**
>
> - The packager compiles the .csproj files for packaging.
> - You must specify Configuration to Package (see below).
> - You do not have to check in a .nuspec file. If you do check one in,    the packager honors its settings and replaces tokens such as $id$ and 
>     $description$.
>
> **Specify .nuspec files (for example, `**\*.nuspec`) for more complex projects, such as multi-platform scenarios in which you need to
>   compile and package in separate steps. In this case:**
>
> - The packager does not compile the .csproj files for packaging.
> - Each project is packaged only if it has a .nuspec file checked in.
> - The packager does not replace tokens in the .nuspec file (except the     element, see Use build number to version package,
>     below).    You must supply values for elements such as  and
>     .    The most common way to do this is to hardcode the
>     values in the    .nuspec file.

Please double check your arguments , more details please refer this tutorial-- [**Pack NuGet packages**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget#pack-nuget-packages).

Besides you could also [enable verbose debug mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) by adding `system.debug=true` to get a more detail build log info for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks very much.